# Compact rings are profinite

Tags: galois-theory, profinite-groups

Still another question about an exercise in Lenstra's [Galois Theory for Schemes](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf).

The purpose of Exercise 1.18 is to demonstrate that a compact, Hausdorff topological ring $R$ (with unity) is a profinite ring.  Lenstra breaks the argument up into four pieces, and I'm fairly confident that I've resolved the last three, and a portion of the first part; however there is still one aspect of it that I can't seem to establish (which seems to me like it should be the easiest out of all of them, but nevertheless…).  The statement is:

> (a) For an open neighborhood $U$ of 0 in $R$, let $V = \{x \in R : RxR\subset U\}$. Prove that $V$ is a neighborhood of 0 in $R$.  If moreover $U$ is an additive subgroup of $R$, prove that $V$ is an open two-sided ideal of $R$.

Proving that U being an additive subgroup implies that $V$ is an open two-sided ideal is straightforward, but I can't seem to show that $V$ is a neighborhood of 0.  I'm certain that the argument is short and simple, but for some reason it alludes me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $0$.  For every pair $(a,b)\in R\times R$, there is a neighborhood $W_{a,b}$ of this pair and there is a neighborhood $V_{a,b}$ of $0$ such that, whenever $(a',b')\in W_{a,b}$ and $x\in V_{a,b}$, then $a'xb'\in U$ (because multiplication is continuous and $a0b=0$).  By compactness, finitely many of the $W_{a,b}$'s cover $R\times R$. The intersection of the finitely many corresponding $V_{a,b}$'s will be included in your $V$, so the latter is a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Forgive my ineptitude, but… I see how, for any pair $(a,b)\in R\times R$ the continuity of multiplication (in particular, of the map $m_{ab}(x)=axb$) and the fact that $m_{ab}(0)=a0b=0\in U$ implies that there is a neighborhood $V_{ab}$ of $0$ so that $m_{ab}(V_{ab})\subset U$ (i.e. $axb\in U$ for all $x\in V_{ab}$), but I don't see where the $W_{ab}$ come from… what (obvious) fact am I missing?

Comment: Oh, actually, the continuity of the map $m:R\times R\times R\rightarrow R$ given by $m(a,b,x)=axb$ and the fact that $m(a,b,0)=a0b=0\in U$ implies that there is a neighborhood $W_{ab}'$ of $(a,b,0)$ so that $m(W_{ab'})\subset U$.  But $W_{ab}'$ can be broken into $W_{ab}\times V_{ab}$ for some neighborhood $W_{ab}$ of $(a,b)\in R\times R$ and neighborhood $V_{ab}$ of $0$ in $R$, and $m(W_{ab}')\subset U$ translates into precisely what you said.  Cool, I think I've got it then.  Thanks!